# Netty 4 leak exception at HttpObjectAggregator

Tags: java, networking, netty

I'm getting an exception on my netty server while it's under heavy load. (Testing with LOIC etc...) I want to know that I do something wrong or it's a bug in the HttpObjectAggregator.

```
WARNING: LEAK: ByteBuf was GC'd before being released correctly.  The following stack trace shows where the leaked object was created, rather than where you failed to release it.
io.netty.util.ResourceLeakException: io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf@1c0eeb6
    at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector$DefaultResourceLeak.<init>(ResourceLeakDetector.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector.open(ResourceLeakDetector.java:116)
    at io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.<init>(CompositeByteBuf.java:60)
    at io.netty.buffer.Unpooled.compositeBuffer(Unpooled.java:353)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:138)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:50)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:320)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:173)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:320)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:785)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:100)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:359)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to release the message after handling it. Did you call release() on it ?

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer, I have some questations. I have fixed it by calling release in the next handler but I'm not 100% sure that I did it correctly. When should I call the release method? After finished all read/handling operations on it? I'm using a FullHttpRequest and releasing it after validation and I can work on it without any problems even after releasing, thats ok or I should release it after all handling?

Comment: Release after all handling